# Recursively get file size and file path of images in a folder, except certain subfolders

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, stat

I would like to get a directory path. From there, I'd like to return the file size and filepath for designated image types within the root and subdirectories, but excluding images within subdirectories that don't contain specific words (for example: "old", "Old", "Archive"). Exclusion criteria would be non-case sensitive.

I know the command that would return the file size and filepath of a file format [extension], within a directory [DIR] as the root directory is:
`stat -f '%z %N' [DIR]*.[extension]`

I have the (very poorly written) AppleScript code below that will grab the size and path for tif, psd, psb png and jpg.

What it doesn't do is drill into all subfolders or add in the exclusion criteria (i.e. "old" or "archive"). Could anyone help clean this code up and/or add this functionality? If it could be done with a single terminal command; even better!

```
tell application "Finder"
    
    set the source_folder to choose folder with prompt ¬
        "Select folder to process:"
    
    set this_item to alias (source_folder as text) as string
    
    set folder_path to quoted form of POSIX path of this_item
    
    set tif_Sizes to ""
    set psd_Sizes to ""
    set psb_Sizes to ""
    set png_Sizes to ""
    set jpg_Sizes to ""
    set all_Sizes to ""
    
    try
        
        set tif_Sizes to do shell script "stat -f '%z %N' " & folder_path & "*.tif"
        
    end try
    
    try
        
        set psd_Sizes to do shell script "stat -f '%z %N' " & folder_path & "*.psd"
        
    end try
    
    try
        
        set psb_Sizes to do shell script "stat -f '%z %N' " & folder_path & "*.psb"
        
    end try
    
    try
        
        set png_Sizes to do shell script "stat -f '%z %N' " & folder_path & "*.png"
        
    end try
    
    try
        
        set jpg_Sizes to do shell script "stat -f '%z %N' " & folder_path & "*.jpg"
        
    end try
    
    try
        
        set all_Sizes to tif_Sizes & return & psd_Sizes & return & psb_Sizes
        
    end try
    
end tell
```

3/30 Edit: Turns out I could do this with ExifTool after all! Just needed to add # to the -FileSize# tag to get it to report in bytes!

```
exiftool -i HIDDEN -ext psb -ext psd -ext png -ext tif -ext jpg -filesize# -filename -if5 '$directory !~ /old|archive/i' -r [DIR]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
activate
set searchFolder to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose folder)

set shellScript to "find " & searchFolder & ¬
    " -type d ! \\( -iname '*old*' -o -iname '*archive*' \\) |while read line ;do find \"$line\" -type f \\( -iname '*.psd' -o -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.tif' -o -iname '*.psb' -o -iname '*.png' \\) -maxdepth 1 ;done |sort -f |tr -s '//' |while read line ;do stat -f '%z %N' \"$line\" ;done"

set text item delimiters to linefeed
set theResults to paragraphs of (do shell script shellScript) as text

do shell script "printf " & quoted form of theResults & ¬
    " |cut -w -f1- > /private/tmp/Search_Results.txt"

tell application "Finder" to reveal POSIX file "/private/tmp/Search_Results.txt"
```

**VERSION 2: Added option for recursive or selected folder only search**

```
activate
set searchFolder to quoted form of POSIX path of ¬
    (choose folder with prompt "Select A Folder To Search In")

activate
set searchType to (choose from list {"Root Folder Only Search", "Recursive Folders Search"} ¬
    with title "Search Options" with prompt ¬
    "Search selected folder only or search all folders within the chosen folder?" OK button name ¬
    "OK" cancel button name "Cancel" without empty selection allowed) as text

if searchType = "Root Folder Only Search" then
    set shellScript to "find -E " & searchFolder & ¬
        " -type f -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -iregex '.*\\.(jpg|png|tif|psd|psb)' |sort -f |tr -s '//' |while read line ;do stat -f '%z %N' \"$line\"  ;done"
else
    set shellScript to "find " & searchFolder & ¬
        " -type d ! \\( -iname '*old*' -o -iname '*archive*' \\) |while read line ;do find -E \"$line\" -type f -iregex '.*\\.(jpg|png|tif|psd|psb)' -maxdepth 1 ;done |sort -f |tr -s '//' |while read line ;do stat -f '%z %N' \"$line\" ;done"
end if

set text item delimiters to linefeed
set theResults to paragraphs of (do shell script shellScript) as text

do shell script "printf " & quoted form of theResults & ¬
    " |cut -w -f1- > /private/tmp/Search_Results.txt"

tell application "Finder" to reveal POSIX file "/private/tmp/Search_Results.txt"
```

**VERSION 3: Added option for recursive or selected folder only search and option to enter the file extensions to search for.**

*NOTE: This option will not allow you to exclude certain folders from the recursive search. It will either search the root folder or the root folder and all of its sub folders.*

```
set {leftSideOfRegex, rightSideOfRegex} to {"'.*\\.(", ")'"}

set text item delimiters to "|"

activate
set searchCriteria to words of text returned of ¬
    (display dialog "Enter file extensions to be searched." & linefeed & ¬
        "(extension... followed by a comma and space)" default answer ¬
        "png, tif, psd, jpg, psb" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2 cancel button 1) as text

activate
set searchFolder to quoted form of POSIX path of ¬
    (choose folder with prompt "Select A Folder To Search In")

activate
set searchType to (choose from list {"Root Folder Only Search", "Recursive Folders Search"} ¬
    with title "Search Options" with prompt ¬
    "Search selected folder only or search all folders within the chosen folder?" OK button name ¬
    "OK" cancel button name "Cancel" without empty selection allowed) as text

if searchType = "Root Folder Only Search" then
    set shellScript to "find -E " & searchFolder & ¬
        " -type f -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -iregex " & ¬
        leftSideOfRegex & searchCriteria & rightSideOfRegex & ¬
        " |sort -f |tr -s '//' |while read line ;do stat -f '%z %N' \"$line\" ;done"
else
    set shellScript to "find -E " & searchFolder & ¬
        " -type f -mindepth 1 -iregex " & ¬
        leftSideOfRegex & searchCriteria & rightSideOfRegex & ¬
        " |sort -f |tr -s '//' |while read line ;do stat -f '%z %N' \"$line\" ;done"
end if

set text item delimiters to linefeed
set theResults to paragraphs of (do shell script shellScript) as text

do shell script "printf " & quoted form of theResults & ¬
    " |cut -w -f1- > /private/tmp/Search_Results.txt"

tell application "Finder" to reveal POSIX file "/private/tmp/Search_Results.txt"
```

Comment: Hey @wch1zpink thank you for this solution. It works pretty well, but has a few issues: (1) could it return the filesize in bytes instead? (2) missing a return between different file types (3) could it return the list without each line being in quotes?

Comment: Hey @wch1zpink not quite. The exclusion of "old" and "archive" applies to the folder names, not the file names, and it appears the code is drilling into folders that have "old" or "archive" in their names. Also, the sizes don't report the same as what the Finder reports... for example, with stat I get 30279 bytes for a file that is reported as 30kb in the Finder; whereas yours reports it as 64.

Comment: Mockman's file size format is what I was looking for (not human readable... I'm formatting it after receiving to match what is displayed in the Finder).

Comment: Hey @wch1zpink, looks like that may do it! I believe I just need that shellScript with a do shell script added. Not sure what all the other stuff below it does, but those results are the same as if I clip it after running the shellScript code. Thank you!

Comment: You are more than welcome. However, a proper way to thank us would be to upvote our posts.  I say "our" because @Mockman also put a significant amount of effort into a solution for you so in my opinion he deserves a +1 ..  If you feel that I provided the solution… please mark my post as the accepted answer. ;)

Comment: I agree, @wch1zpink, both you and Mockman were great! I tried to upvote and got this: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." Was able to mark your answer as correct though.

Comment: Cool. I believe I've done it @wch1zpink as you suggested. LMK if I can do anything else. Cheers...

Comment: Hey @wch1zpink, after further testing looks like there are still 3 issues with the code. (1) your resulting path has 2 forward slashes prior to the filename; I believe due to the way your searchFolder is formatted? Returns correct if I use the first 2 lines of Mockman's code with your code. (2) It still excludes files that have "old" in the names, as opposed to just folders. (3) File extension for tif needs to be .tif, not .tiff.

Comment: @wch1zpink Looks good. Chris… good question. One suggestion to consider… using -E and -regex to consolidate the slew of 'or' commands. For example, `find -E . -regex '.*\.(jpg|png|tif|psd|psb)$'`. The -E engages extended regex, required so that each of the extensions will be included with a single regex.

Comment: By the way, an earlier comment raised the issue of the size being represented as '64' rather than '30279'. In this case, the 'block size' is 64 and the 'byte size' is '30279'. The 'device block size' is typically 512 bytes per block so 64 blocks is an approximation (made more approximate because it is actually 'blocks allocated'). If you use the `-ls` option with find on that specific file, you should see a 64 in column 2 and 30279 in column 7. In `stat`, the `z` format gets bytes while the `b` format gets blocks allocated.

Comment: Mockman, thanks for the tip on -E and -regex. I am changing those extensions based on user interaction so that makes it a bit easier to do the substitutions. I tried adding this to wch1zpink's code but got an error; perhaps placed in the wrong spot? @wch1zpink, could you help amend your code with this? Also, if I just wanted to return the files within the root folder and not drill into sub folders, what would that code look like? I'm allowing the user to choose the folder names they want to exclude, include root level only, or everything, and amending the code accordingly.

Comment: @Chris I think my updates are exactly what you're looking for.  As a side-note, while it's generally my pleasure helping others with code, in a sense, my motivations are selfish. The more I help others, the better I get. So helping you helps me.  I'm not some guru who new exactly how to help you.  I tried this… this didn't work, I tried that..part of that worked..What if I try part of this & part of that, etc. My point is, Even if you fail, you're still learning through trial and error.  It will be to your advantage to try and solve some of your problems on your own before turning to others.

Comment: @wcg1zpink thank you. Sound advice. I try to pick my battles for a better balance, otherwise I become obsessed. Sometimes not worth it. In this case, I spent many hours. Turns out all I had to do was add a # to my original code to get what I needed which someone helped me realize! Still learned from your and Mockman's code though!

Answer (score 2):

There are probably a few ways to do this but this will create a list of lists of each image kind. I only have jpg and png on my system so I ignored the other kinds — well, I included tif to show what happens when there aren't any images of that kind.

It starts by choosing the top level directory and then setting some variables.

It then loops through each image kind and finds each file of that kind within the directory tree under the top level. It excludes any files containing the strings 'old' and 'archive' and then lists the results. It then applies `cut` to remove everything that's not the size or path. It is set to keep columns 72-78 and then from column 92 to the end of the line. Depending upon the file sizes, you will likely have to adjust them.

Once it finishes each image kind, you'll end up with a list of each kind that contains a list of every matching file/size. I show how to coerce back to paragraphs so you should be able to use the data in a variety of ways.

```
set the source_folder to (choose folder with prompt "Select folder to process:") as text
set folder_path to quoted form of POSIX path of (text 1 thru -2 of source_folder)

set png_sz to {}
set jpg_sz to {}
set tif_sz to {}

set kindList to {"png", "jpg", "tif"}
set sizesList to a reference to {png_sz, jpg_sz, tif_sz}

repeat with xx from 1 to length of kindList
    item xx of kindList
    set sFindCut to "find " & folder_path & " -name '*." & item xx of kindList & "' ! -name '*old*' ! -name '*archive*' -ls | cut -b72-78,92-"
    set pl to do shell script sFindCut
    set (item xx of sizesList) to paragraphs of pl
end repeat

-- use the data
sizesList -- list of each file kind
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
item 1 of sizesList as text -- all png as paragraphs
set all_sizes to item 1 of sizesList & item 2 of sizesList as text
```

Here is the shell command that finds the matching files and cuts the columns.

```
"find '/Users/username/Pictures/samples/mobile/level0' -name '*.png' ! -name '*old*' ! -name '*archive*' -ls | cut -b72-78,92-"
```

To break it down, it finds files whose name ends with '.png' but excluding those containing 'old' or 'archive' and then lists them. Note that files containing those words anywhere within their path will be excluded.

This is what a given item will look like: First a find result and then after the cut. While you're working things out, remove the 'cut' part and just look at the find results. I'd also recommend testing it with just a single image type as it's easier to see what's going on that way.

```
154336000      124 -rw-r--r--    1 username          staff              52114 21 Jul  2021 ./down1/unbase-0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef.png

52114 /Users/username/Pictures/samples/mobile/level0/down1/unbase-0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef.png
```

If anything needs elaborating, let me know.

Comment: Thank you @Mockman. To clarify, does this recursively look within subfolders, or just the root folder? Also, is this excluding IMAGES that have "old" or "archive" in the image names, or is it excluding entire SUB-FOLDERS containing "old" or "archive" in them? What I'm looking for is all files within the root folder and to drill down into subfolders, but skip subfolders (and all files/folders within) that have "old" or "archive" in the subfolder names.

Comment: `Find` recurses into all sub-folders unless blocked (for example with -maxdepth or -prune options). Using '-name' applies the exclusion to file names. Use '-path or -ipath' to exclude based on each file's path. Again, I would recommend testing a stripped-down version of the script (one image kind, limited number of directories, remove the cut sequence) to see for yourself what gets included. You can read up on `find` using `man find` in the Terminal, and for something more readable and with more depth, look up `gnu findutils`.

Comment: @Mockman, I changed "! -name" to "! -ipath" in the two spots in your code. This worked to exclude files within those folders, but it also excluded those images that had the exclusions in the filenames as well. Is there a way to just do the exclusion based on the folder name and not the filename? Also, for some reason some of the returned paths begin with a "M" instead of a forward slash?

Comment: The latter issue is likely related to the numbers used in the `cut` command. In my example, I wanted to keep characters 72-78 of each line (file size) and everything from 92 onward. If any of your file sizes are longer than 6 digits (i.e. size > 1MB) then you would need to adjust the numbers. Or if the largest file only requires 5 digits (i.e. size < 100K), you would adjust in the other direction.

Comment: @Mockman, is there a way to add additional filetypes in the single shell command line with "or" statements, or would that need to be done with separate commands?

Comment: @Mockman, file sizes could range from  ~ 1 kb to 10+ GB so would need to be flexible enough to handle anything in between

Comment: @wch1zpink Strange, it sorted the output for me. I'll try and set up a different directory tree and test. I'll let the OP advise whether he has many .app files in his image folders but I'm concerned that it would clutter the command. As to the file sizes, as is, it aids the cut command. I'm not sure how the columns would line up if I used human-readable. I should figure that out though. Good suggestion.

Comment: Yes, you can string together 'or' expressions, using either `-or` or `-o` (as well as 'and' expressions using either `-add` or `-a`).

Comment: @Mockman it would be more than just .app files.  The same thing will happen with .scptd bundle files and .workflow files, etc.

Comment: @Mockman & wch1zpink, the only thing that should be within the root folder being searched should technically be additional folders and images, and possibly hidden files.

Comment: BTW - the size format Mockman presented is what I was looking for... am doing the math myself after receiving it.